# Possible to move downloaded mp3s from application to iPod?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

I was looking to code an iPhone application however, i was not sure if the following is possible :

- Download an mp3 from an external site (through the application)
- Once the mp3 has been downloaded, automatically add it to the usual iPod application, so it is visible in the user ipod songs list.
- Same for videos too (download video[mp4] and directly transfer it to the usual videos app)

If the above is not possible, can i directly play the downloaded mp3 in my application ? What would i require to play an mp3 in my application ? Are there open source mp3 players available that i can integrate with my application ?

Thanks for any help, i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Once the mp3 has been downloaded, automatically add it to the usual iPod application, so it is visible in the user ipod songs list.

No, that's not possible. The iPod library is not writable by third-party apps.

> Same for videos too (download video[mp4] and directly transfer it to the usual videos app)

Not possible, either.